# nodejs & postgres - SQL getting executed out of order - newbie question, getting unique constraint error

Tags: node.js

it seems the SQL INSERT seems to be out of order(while executing) , all I am doing is checking if the record is present, if it is not present writing few rows, else if the record present updating it,
hope you can answer  my newbie question:
Code snippet below

I am expecting if the record is present the code should execute the path of update, else it should insert , instead it is giving unique constraint error
`

```
const fs = require("fs");
const pg = require('pg');
const crypto = require("crypto"); 

// ~~~ GLOBAL DB Connection ~~~
const connection_string = 'postgres://postgres:PostgreSQLXXX@localhost:5432/postgres';
const client = new pg.Client(connection_string);
client.connect();


var input_sql_file="SQL_sample_input_1_0.txt";
process_SQL_text_file(input_sql_file);// call function

function process_SQL_text_file(ip_file_name)
{
   var is_record_present=false;
   var line_no=0;
   const readline = require('readline');
  
   const rl = readline.createInterface({
       input: fs.createReadStream(ip_file_name),
       terminal: false
   });

// READ & process EACH ROW   
rl.on('line', (line) => {
  line_no++;

   var current_SQL_stripped;
   var Orginal_SQL_text=line;
   
   var HASH_SHA256 = crypto.createHash('sha256').update(Orginal_SQL_text).digest('hex');
   var SQL_find = `SELECT  * from SQL_Summary WHERE SQL_Hash='${HASH_SHA256}'`;

  try 
  {
    client.query(SQL_find) // find hash  record
      .then( (res) => {
        if((res.rows== null) || (res.rows.length < 1))
        {
            // Insert record TABLE 1
            var SQL_Insert=`INSERT INTO sql_summary(SQL_text,sql_hash,usage_count) VALUES('${Orginal_SQL_text}','${HASH_SHA256}',1)`;
            //console.log("SQL_Insert:",SQL_Insert);
            client.query(SQL_Insert) // Insert row
            .then((res2) => {
              var SQL_insert_multi= `INSERT INTO table_names_log (table_name,SQL_hash,usage_count) VALUES('t1','${HASH_SHA256}',1),('t2','${HASH_SHA256}',1),('t3','${HASH_SHA256}',1)`;
              client.query(SQL_insert_multi);
              
            })
            .finally(() => {
              console.log("in 'finally:' in INSERT  ...");
            })
        } else // record present 
        {
          var SQL_update=`UPDATE sql_summary SET usage_count=usage_count+1 WHERE SQL_hash='${HASH_SHA256}'`;
          //console.log("SQL_update:",SQL_update);
          client.query(SQL_update) 

        }

    })
    .finally(() => {
      console.log("finally block: is_record_present:",is_record_present);

      });  
    } catch(err)
      {
        console.log("Catch err",err)
      }
})// end of  "rl'on('line')

rl.on('close', () => {
  console.log("end of file, processed, line:",line_no)
   }); // end of "rl.on('close'"

} // end of function
```

`

Comment: I would truely appreciate anyone to look at my code & see if any 'newbie' mistakes I am making & comment, rather than general comments !

Answer (score 0):

I suggest that instead of writing your own [UPSERT](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/upsert), you use the tools available in the database. For recent versions of Postgres, this would be the `ON CONFLICT` clause for `INSERT` ([link](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/15/sql-insert.html)) or the `MERGE` command ([link](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/15/sql-merge.html)).

Without looking all the way through your code, doing UPSERTs is hard, and your code is certainly not

Comment: my the main question is how to handle multiple SQLs on the function

Comment: It isn't clear why having multiple queries is a problem, but, again, your logic can be simplified by using more modern Postgres commands.